# NSMutableArray keep objects at indexSet

Tags: objective-c, nsindexset

I am on Xcode 8.2, OSX not iOS, Objective-C

I have an NSMutableArray and an  NSIndexSet. I want to remove ALL items of the array EXCEPT those at the NSIndexSet. So basically something like

```
[array keepObjectsAtIndexes:indexSet]; // just to carify i know this doesnt exist
```

What's the best way to do this? Can i somehow 'reverse' the index set?

Comment: `NSMutableIndexSet *indexSetToRemove = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] initWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [array count])] [indexSetToRemove removeIndexes:indexSetToKeep]; [array removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexSetToRemove];` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this even without creating unnecessary arrays:

```objc
// Initial array
NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[@"one", @"two", @"three", @"four", @"five"]];

// Indices we want to keep
NSIndexSet* indexSet = [[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(1, 3)];

// Preparing reversed index set
NSMutableIndexSet *indexSetToRemove = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] initWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [array count])];
[indexSetToRemove removeIndexes:indexSet];

// Removing objects from that set
[array removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexSetToRemove];
```

The output will be:

```
2017-05-11 20:10:22.317 Untitled 15[46504:32887351] (
    two,
    three,
    four
)
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can construct an inverse of a given `NSIndexSet` by constructing an index set that has all indexes in range `0`..`arrayCount-1`, inclusive, and then removing the indexes in your `indexSet` from it:

```
NSMutableIndexSet *indexesToRemove = [NSMutableIndexSet initWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, array.count)];
[indexesToRemove removeIndexes:indexesToKeep];
[array removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexesToRemove];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the objects with `objectsAtIndexes` and replace the entire objects with the result.

```
NSArray *temp = [array objectsAtIndexes:indexSet];
[array replaceObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, array.count) withObjectsFromArray: temp];
```